# howto implement a datasource property in a custom control using .net compact framework

Tags: .net, data-binding, user-controls, compact-framework, custom-controls

Anybody knows how to create a User Control that Supports Complex Data Binding in .Net Compact framework ?

I can't find the ComplexBindingPropertiesAttribute Class. The Walktrough provided by MS [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233813%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use that example.

If you look at the [ComplexBindingPropertyAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.complexbindingpropertiesattribute%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) class, you will see that it says under **Version Information**:

**.NET Framework**
Supported in: 3.5, 3.0, 2.0

It does NOT say that it supports any version of the Compact Framework.

Comment: Hi JP2code, thanks for the hint. Do you know how complex databinding with design time support is realised in compact framework?

Comment: Personally, I have found design time support to not be that good in the Compact world. I fill a `DataTable` in my code and simply assign that to my `Controls` as I need in the code.